# Getting and setting date in DATETIMEPICK_CLASS element

Tags: c++, winapi, time

I am creating time picker element described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I am writing code in C++ using simple winapi calls

I cannot find any examples of how to actually get and set time within this element programmatically.

First of all, the element initializes with some random time at program startup (which does not even match system time) and I would like it to initialize with `00:00`. How do I do that?

Second question is what method should I use to get time value from control element. I have tried  `GetWindowText()` with some success but I am not sure if this is the correct solution.

The example of code that I use to initialize is provided below

```
    /* TIMER2*/
    dtmTimer2 = CreateWindowEx( //
            /* Extended Style   */0, //
            /* Class Name       */DATETIMEPICK_CLASS, //
            /* Element Name     */GUI_TIMER2_LABEL, //
            /* Style            */(WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD |WS_VISIBLE | DTS_TIMEFORMAT), //
            /* X Position       */GUI_TIMER2_POS_X, //
            /* Y Position       */GUI_TIMER2_POS_Y, //
            /* Width            */GUI_TIMER2_WIDTH, //
            /* Height           */GUI_TIMER2_HEIGHT, //
            /* Parent Window    */hwnd, //
            /* Menu             */NULL, //
            /* Instance         */NULL, //
            /* Parameter        */NULL);
    SendMessage(dtmTimer2, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, MAKELPARAM(TRUE, 0));
    SendMessage(dtmTimer2, DTM_SETFORMAT, 0, (LPARAM) "HH:MM");
```

It seems like I am missing something really obvious here. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The messages you need are [`DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761769.aspx) and [`DTM_SETSYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761782.aspx) (or their corresponding macros) which operate using `SYSTEMTIME` structs.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. the word **system** has initially confused me. I though that this will mess with actual system time. Now I understand it. Thanx